# Respond to user and continue to run async functions

Tags: aiohttp

I want to respond to user as soon as I received the request, then continue to save data to database

```
async def index(request):
    data = await request.post()
    response.write("done")
    async with request.app.mysqlpool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute("INSERT INTO ...")
```

If I try to wrap the part after request.write to separate function and than call it with run_in_executor - it doesn't allow awaitable functions inside (TypeError: coroutines cannot be used with run_in_executor())

Is there a way to do it in aiohttp?

Answer (score 2):

Push `await response.drain()` just after `response.write(...)` call.

It doesn't exactly guarantee that data are sent through the wire but it's the closest solution.

Comment: In the end I did it like this: body = json.dumps({"status": "success"}).encode("utf8")
        resp = web.StreamResponse(headers={
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "content-length": str(len(body)),
        })
        await resp.prepare(self.request)
        resp.write(body)
        await resp.drain()
        await resp.write_eof()